# Makemagrations - django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column does not exist

Tags: django, database, django-models, postgis

I can't understand what is wrong. I can't add new fields to a model, every time I run `makemigrations` I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "..." does not exist
```

Yes the column doesn't exist. That is why I want to run a migration.

```
'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
```

Comment: I can't rename a field either. Gives me the same error.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but it's only happening for me when I try to run tests. Very frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

try to make a rollback:

1. Go into the migrations folder in your django app.
2. Look for the migration file where you would like to go back to. (for example 0012_post_category.py)
3. go in the terminal write: ./manage.py migrate yourAppName 0012 (this is just the example number) and hit enter
4. if everything goes well. Delete the other migrations which came after this number in your migrations folder.

or try with `python manage.py syncdb`

Comment: Thanks or your suggestions. I only have _init.py_ and 0001_initial.py in my migrations folder. So I can't really roll back. I tried MyAppName 0001. And syncdb is an "unknown" command.